# What do I get if someone adds bounty to my question?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounty-badges

This hasn't happened to me yet, but there should be a reward when someone adds a bounty to my question. I was thinking either a rep increase or a badge. The reason is because someone found my question worthy enough to pay with his/her own rep to find an answer to it. I would want a badge for that!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What do you get? Hopefully, **a good answer to your question**, and one that you didn't have to pay for yourself with your *own* hard-earned reputation.

You probably also get an upvote, and maybe someone's earnest attempt to clean up and improve your question to attract the best answers possible, around the time that they set the bounty.

And then the attention attracted by the bounty causes prospective answerers to look at your question, and several of them probably upvote it as well (at least, if it's worth upvoting!).

Each upvote on a question nets you +5 reputation. Good answers to a problem you have are invaluable.

Answer (score 3):

Badges are mainly used to encourage behaviour that we want to see more of. There are already a lot of badges that you can get from asking good questions, so I see this as redundant.

Comment: its a way to encourage ppl to ask good question....isnt that the behavior that we want to see more???

Comment: @xs2bush Yes, but there are already several badges that encourage that behaviour. I don't think adding more would help, and adding bounties isn't always a good indicator of a good question. Personally, I usually just add them to questions whose answer is important to me, not questions that are particularly well-asked.